# Why doesn't action (in ASP.NET MVC 4) run with onclick event?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, onclick, actionlink

My action runs without an onclick event but it doesn't run with an onclick event (only the JavaScript function runs well).

I use this in the View:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Documents", "Home", New With {.id = item.Id}, New With {.id = item.Id, .onclick="return showMenu("+item.Id+")"})
```

And this is the JavaScript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMenu(id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id).parentNode.getElementsByClassName("subItem")[0] != undefined) {
        if (document.getElementById) {
            thisMenu = document.getElementById(id).parentNode.getElementsByClassName("subItem")[0].style
            if (thisMenu.display == "block") {
                thisMenu.display = "none"
            }
            else {
                thisMenu.display = "block"
            }
            return false
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the call to action run?

Answer (score 0):

If `showMenu` returns false, the form will not post.

Answer (score 0):

When you return false on an `onclick` event of a link (`<a>` tag) you are telling the browser not to follow the link. If you want the link to be followed, you should make sure you return true.

Comment: You should rethink your design then because navigating to another page fully blows away the current page you are viewing (unless you are using frames). It looks like you are toggling the visibility of something with your javascript. Can that be done via a separate `<a>` tag in that page?